# Where can I find detail on interpreting the exo-planet transit-data graphics used in the Zooniverse Project?

Tags: exoplanet, kepler, light-curve

I'm participating in the Zooniverse Exoplanet-explorers project (transit method), which provides only minimal guidance on interpreting their light curve and transit data graphics, as visible here:
 https://www.zooniverse.org/projects/ianc2/exoplanet-explorers/classify

Can anyone point me to source(s) that will help me read these graphs in detail, pls?

(Re own comment below, suggest view [Weird example](https://www.zooniverse.org/projects/ianc2/exoplanet-explorers/talk/820/277985?comment=457728&page=1))

UPDATE: Just located [NASA Exo-PLanet Archive](http://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/applications/ETSS/Kepler_index.html) which looks like it might hold what iSeek. But further recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to understand what has been done with the data that you see there, or what we can learn from fitted transit curves?

Comment: As part of a "crowd", helping classify data including, occasionally, transiting exo-planets, I would like to be able to go a little deeper into the interpretation of the graphics (I assume you've seen the above link to what might be "standard" representations, in which case I'm seeking a tutorial on their detailed interpretation. What exactly do the numbers on the graphs represent (not defined on the Zooniverse site); how does one interpret deviations from the classic patterns" See e.g. 2nd link I'll shortly add to the original Question, please.